# Flex Ajax Bridge, or any other push method with ColdFusion?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, coldfusion, websocket, server-sent-events

Is it easy to implement [Flex Ajax Bridge](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ajaxbridge_2.html) with ColdFusion?  Where can I learn how to use it?  My frontend is pure HTML+JS and I just need the push capability.  I thought of using  [Websocket Event Gateway](https://github.com/nmische/cf-websocket-gateway/wiki/) and [Server Sent Event (aka EventSource)](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/01/server-sent-events-with-html5-and.html) but seems like they don't have much browser support quite yet.  Any experience with either one of them are welcome.  Any pure jQuery short/long polling option?  Any good Server Sent Event polyfill solution available for older browsers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henry,

Its pretty easy to use the Flex-Ajax Bridge. Take a look at my blog posts on BlazeDS. http://nil.checksite.co.uk/index.cfm/BlazeDS
They all use the Flex-Ajax Bridge, but be aware, the FA Bridge and BlazeDS do not do push.  Its all polling or amf. You'd need to look at LiveCycle for more protocols.

Comet is also longpolling not push.

The closest you're going to get to "push" is interfacing with websockets and [pusher](http://pusher.com/) (you just know that Ben Nadel [has written about this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1955-Pushing-Base64-Encoded-Images-Over-HTML5-WebSockets-With-Pusher-And-ColdFusion.htm)) or using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) with [now.js](http://nowjs.com/).

Comment: Thx, in your opinion, what's better? FABridge or HTML5 EventSource with Polyfill?

Comment: Never used EventSource or Polyfill, so couldn't possibly comment authoratively, but polyfill does give you the benefit of fallback that you don't really get from the FABridge, because you MUST have the flash widget to provide the connection to Blaze. A quick glance at EventSource and Polyfill - I would definitely look at node.js and now.js as an alternative.

Comment: Thx, but I want to keep the server side as simple as possible, so CF9 only and maybe BlazeDS at most.  Did FABridge get any update/enhancement in Flex 4?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it since it would add considerable overhead just for push messaging.  I would recommend you look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) for push messaging over long polling or [Solace's Web Messaging](http://solacesystems.com/solutions/web-messaging/) which I've worked with and was very good.

PS.  I have no clue about this working with Coldfusion.

Comment: How to implement a "Comet" solution with ColdFusion and jQuery?  and how does Solace's Web Messaging work?  Thank you.

Comment: I have no experience with Coldfusion, so you're on your own for that one.  Looking online, things doesn't look too good for CF in the pushing department.

Comment: It seems to me that CF is a request based language (like PHP) which would mean that pushing (in the real sense of pushing) is impossible, but long polling is.  I can't seem to find any long polling libraries for CF, so either invent your own or just use regular client side polling.

Comment: CF9 has event gateway and BlazeDS built-in that can do push to Flex / Flex-Ajax Bridge.  And yes, it can do long polling easily.

Comment: Yeah, but long polling != pushing.

Comment: event gateway can do true pushing, like to JMS or XMPP

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something that BlazeDS would be good for... http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS

Comment: Flex Ajax Bridge will make use of BlazeDS.. yes.  BlazeDS is fine, the weakest link seems to be Flex Ajax Bridge.