# Instant Messenger in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, httpclient

I am new to ColdFusion & I want to create an instant messenger in it that is very much similar to the chat clients of Google and Facebook?

So where to start and what are the technologies to go through as I am unable to understand the  topic?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex Ajax Bridge, or any other push method with ColdFusion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586625/flex-ajax-bridge-or-any-other-push-method-with-coldfusion)

Comment: Downvote because it's such a nebulous question, and doesn't indicate any research on the part of the person asking the question.  Recommend doing some of your own investigation and come back with more targetted questions.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is a huge topic potentially, but for kicks here is some jquery+cfm+ajax chat code I wrote a while back that may get some ideas rolling for you:

ajax_chat_client.cfm

```
<div id="chatlog">

</div>

<input type="text" name="message" id="chat_message"> <input type="button" value="post" onclick="sendMessage()">

<br>Last HTTP Request made:
<span id="last_request_time"></span>

<style>
#chatlog {

        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
        border: thin black solid;

}
</style>

<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" /></script>
<script>

var lastMessage = 0;

function sendMessage(){
        $.get("ajax_chat_post.cfm?message=" + escape($("#chat_message").val()));
        $("#chat_message").val("");
}

function checkNewPosts()
{
        $("#last_request_time").html(new Date().getTime());
        $.getJSON('ajax_chat_get.cfm?lastchat=' + lastMessage, function(data){

                while(data.length > lastMessage)
                {
                        $("#chatlog").prepend((lastMessage+1) + ') ' + data[lastMessage] + '<br>');

                        lastMessage++;

                }


                setTimeout(checkNewPosts(), 500);

        });

}

 $(document).ready(function(){


        checkNewPosts();


 });

</script>
```

ajax_chat_get.cfm

```
<cfapplication name="chatter">

<cfset threadLife = 30000><!--- thirty seconds --->


<cfset threadStart = getTickCount()>
<cfparam name="lastchat" default="0">

<cfif not IsDefined("application.chatlog")>
        <cfset application.chatlog = ArrayNew(1)>
</cfif>

<cfloop condition="threadLife+threadStart GT getTickCount()">

        <cfoutput>

                <cfif ArrayLen(application.chatlog) GT lastchat>
                                #SerializeJSON(application.chatlog)#
                        <cfabort>
                </cfif>

                <cfthread action="sleep" duration="500" />

        </cfoutput>

</cfloop>
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(ArrayNew(1))#</cfoutput>
```

ajax_chat_post.cfm

```
<cfapplication name="chatter">

<cfif not IsDefined("application.chatlog")>
        <cfset application.chatlog = ArrayNew(1)>
</cfif>

<cfparam name="message" default="">

<cfif len(message)>
        <cfset arrayAppend(application.chatlog, message)>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Note the inclusion of jquery - version shouldn't matter, though.

Comment: Thanks for your great info.
I want to ask one more thing that is it possible to keep history of the chat,smiley support,chatting one to one with many persons.

Comment: Sure, you could extend this is a bunch of different ways - the sky's the limit!  In my code, I just have one big pool (application.chatlog) of chat history that everyone shares - you could easily build separate pools for chat histories between individual users.  Smiley-faces and stuff like that is just more display logic on the jquery side.

Comment: You could keep a history of the chat very easily by using a database layer for persistance, rather than just stuffing messages in the application scope like I'm doing here.

Comment: Thanks @Jake Feasel information what you gave is really great. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help.  If that resolves it for you, please mark this as the approved answer.  Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5037/discussion-between-jake-feasel-and-ankur-verma)